# An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/project into a docker

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to got an image in docker on a way I could write `docker-compose up --build` and container works.

But I am getting this error when I run `docker-compose up` after building the image:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/project
```

I solved the problem the problem before by adding `RUN npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular` in the `Dockerfile` but then other dependencies did not work.

I think is a problem with the folders in docker but I do not know what I am missing.

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12.16.3

# Puerto entorno dev
EXPOSE 4200
# Puerto livereload
EXPOSE 49153
# Puerto Test
EXPOSE 9876
# Puerto e2e
EXPOSE 49152 

RUN apt update

# Instalamos angular cli en nuestra imágen
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8

RUN mkdir /project

COPY . /project/

WORKDIR /project

RUN npm install --yes
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  client-angular:
    image: algoritmofifo
    build: .
    command: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - .:/project  
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
      - 49153:49153
      - 9876:9876
      - 49152:49152
```

Comment: The `volumes:` are overwriting the code you `COPY` into your image, and the `node_modules` tree that `npm install` creates.  I'd recommend deleting that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@7.3.9
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit why I should implement your answer, please? I still get the same error

Comment: u could add ur node js path then install the package.json  and run npm install, in ur example u dont have  npm install before  # Instalamos angular cli en nuestra imágen
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@8

Comment: Thanks. I finally understood what happen. The volume was overwriting the `node_modules` as mention David Maze in the comment above.